# How to read a PPM file into standard input

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, ppm

I'm having trouble figuring out how to read in a ppm file into the standard input, storing the pixels in a 2- dimensional array of new_pix in C.  I don't really know How to get it started. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you can get the dimensions of the image from the file (call them `W` and `H`). If not, read about the format from [wikipedia](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Netpbm_format)

Now, you need to allocate memory for the 2d-array you want to make. You will need a `char **buf` (assuming 8-bit grayscale. You can use `long` or `long long` for 32/64 bit images.

Next allocate the space for pointers where you will store the rows of the image.

```
buf=(char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*H);
```

Next, you need to allocate space for each row and read it from stdin (you can use `scanf` in a loop).

```
for(int y=0;y<H;y++){
  buf[y]=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*W);
  for(int x=0;x<W;x++)
    scanf("%d",&buff[y][x]);
}
```

And you are done! Note that you will have to do checks on malloc return value and limit W and H to sane values if you plan to distribute the code.